# Can I share VPN connection from laptop to other laptop using WiFi

Tags: networking, window, vpn

I have only one Username/Password vpn to server then I want to connect vpn from other laptop on same time too.

here is my network map
[image]

In this image I want to share VPN to A taptop 
So, Can I share vpn to other laptop

Thank you.